# How to bundle a ruby package into an [Objective-C] cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, cocoa, sass

I'm trying to figure out how I could bundle a package, written in Ruby ([Sass](http://sass-lang.com/download.html)) into a Cocoa application (Objective-C, not Ruby Cocoa) for me to execute (via NSTask is fine, unless there is an easy way to bridge ObjC<->Cocoa that I'm not aware of).

The Sass package is something you have to install, using "gem install" or "rake install" -- doing so puts a *ton* of files in my ~/.gem directory.  Since I want anybody who has installed my Cocoa-based application to be able to execute this tool from within my app, I don't want to have the user go through a process of installing anything additional, so I'm hoping to be able to embed everything I need in the Resources directory of my app package.

However, not being that familiar with the internals and structure of Ruby <sub>(Sorry, I'm having trouble just keeping ObjC/Cocoa in my head!)</sub>, It's not clear to me just which of the 1,444 files that got installed in the ~/.gem directory <sub>(Yes, I counted)</sub> I need to embed in the application and what I might need to do to get the directory references, etc. working right.

If anybody has any experience with embedding a ruby tool into a Cocoa application, I would really appreciate your input.  I wasn't expecting this to be so hard, considering that ruby *is* installed on Mac OS X ... but apparently this package is (typically? atypically?) more than just a single script file....

Answer (score 1):

You can install gems into a specific location:

```
GEM_HOME=path/to/your/project/gems gem install sass
```

Then, as part of your build process, copy the folder into your resources. When you want to run sass, find your gem folder. Call ruby like so:

```
NSString *gems_path = …;
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
// you may want to copy NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment and modify it instead
task.environment = @{ @"GEM_HOME": gems_path };
task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/ruby";
task.arguments = @[[gems_path stringByAppendingPaths:@[@"bin",@"sass"]], @"rest", @"of", @"your", @"arguments"];
// add handling for I/O
[task launch];
```

(Typed into github, may have silly mistakes)

Note that you may want to bundle ruby as well (perhaps macruby), to prevent compatibility issues. If not, ensure that you test all versions of OS X that you support, especially 10.9, as ruby was upgrade to 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Major thanks to [@Jacob Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267437/jacob-lukas), I found that simply setting GEM_HOME on `gem install <gem>` didn't correctly attach the dependencies.  So, for my case--where I just need to run a script I'm generating in an Xcode plugin--I ended up with:

`gem install -i ~/xCodeProjects/PluginOne/gems xcodeproj --verbose`

to get the gem(s) & dependencies.  Then, I used:

```
NSString *gems_path = [[bundle resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/gems"];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.environment = @{ @"GEM_HOME" : gems_path };
task.launchPath = @"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby";
task.arguments = @[generatedRubyFilePath];

[task launch];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble doing something similar with Ruby gems so I'll share what worked for me in the hopes that it helps someone in the future.

#### Step 1: Install the Gems

Start by installing the gems you want to use into a folder you can easily locate, such as a `gems` folder inside your project folder. As Stan showed in his answer, use the `-i` option and supply the path to the gems folder when installing the gem.

```
gem install -i /path/to/gem/folder gemName
```

#### Step 2: Add a Copy Files build phase

Add a Copy Files build phase to your app target by choosing Editor > Add Build Phase > Add Copy Files Build Phase. Use the Resources menu to choose a place to copy the gems in the app bundle. If you want the gems in their own folder, add the folder name in the Subpath text field.

Click the Add button to add the files. A sheet opens. Click the Add Other button. Navigate to your gem folder location and select your gem folder. 
Now when you build the project, Xcode will copy the gems into the app bundle.

#### Step 3: Locate the gems folder in the app bundle

Use the `Bundle` class to find standard locations in the bundle, such as the Resources folder. Build a path to the gems folder. You will need it as an environment variable when running the gem.

The folder containing the gems should have a `bin` folder containing the executable files. You would build a path to the executable file and use that path as the first argument when running the gem.

#### Step 4: Configure the command to run the gem

Use the `Process` class, formerly `NSTask`, to run a command-line program, such as a gem. Start by creating a `Process` object.

```
let taskToRun = Process()
```

Set the launch path to the path of the Ruby interpreter.

```
taskToRun.launchPath = "/usr/bin/ruby"
```

Set the environment variable GEM_HOME to the path of your gems folder.

```
taskToRun.environment = ["GEM_HOME" : gemsPath]
```

Set the `arguments` property with a list of arguments. The first argument should be the path to the gem's executable file.

```
let argumentList = [gemExecutablePath, inputURL.path, "-o", outputURL.path]
taskToRun.arguments = argumentList
```

The actual list of arguments depends on the gem you're using.

#### Step 5: Run the gem

On macOS 10.13 and later, call the `run` function to run the gem.

```
do {
    try taskToRun.run()
} catch {
    fatalError("Error running command line tool.")
}
```

On earlier versions of macOS, call the function `launch` to run the gem.

```
taskToRun.launch()
```

You can find more detailed information in the following article:

[Using a Ruby Gem in a Mac App](https://meandmark.com/blog/2019/01/using-a-ruby-gem-in-a-mac-app/)